# Is there a way to use MutationObserver JavaScript API in selenium

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use MutationObserver on selenium to observe change of the element.

But following error have occured in `observe()`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

I found information about the error.
['observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398054/observe-on-mutationobserver-parameter-1-is-not-of-type-node)

According to above stackoverflow page, the error occure when invoke getElement... function before loading dom.

So I tried the way that wait until desired dom be visible,
But the error occur.

I am using

- Python3.6.3
- selenium3.6
- Chrome 64.0.3248.0 (Official Build) canary.

Codes:

main.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary'
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
#options.add_argument('--headless')
with open("execute_script.js") as f:
    script_source = f.read()

driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
driver.get("example.com/index.html")
close_icons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("i.CloseIcon")
if len(close_icons) >= 1:
    for v in close_icons:
        if v.is_displayed():
            v.click()
driver.execute_script(script_source)
```

execute_script.js: this script is loading as a execute script in main.py.

```
let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
let script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "application/javascript";

let str = `
let dom = document.getElementById('last-last');
function getDesiredDom() {
    dom = document.getElementById("last-last");
    if (!dom) {
        console.log("Desired dom does not exist yet")
        setTimeout(getDesiredDom, 500);
    }

}
getDesiredDom();
let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:6788/");
ws.addEventListener("message", (message) => {
    console.log(message.data);
});
ws.onerror = (error) => console.log(error);

let observer_config = {childList: true, attributes: true, characterData: true};

let observer = new MutationObserver((mutation) => {
    for (v of mutation) {
        if (v.type === "childList") {
            for (x of v.addedNodes) {
                if (x.nodeName === '#text') {
                    console.log(x.nodeValue);
                    ws.send(x.nodeValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
observer.observe(dom, observer_config);
`

script.innerHTML = str;
body.appendChild(script)
```

Comment: Backtick is a ES6 functionality and won't work natively in browser. Don't use that in your java script