Wait for an element to exist
I'm trying the below code but I'm getting undefined "length" because the element in the select is not yet created that because I'm using a plugin and this element is inside this plugin template and the plugin take a little more time to load after the DOM loads. What can I do to wait for the element to load?
What I want to do
var select = document.getElementsByClassName("pp_pricing_options")[0];
var plan = localStorage.getItem("Plan");
plan = plan.replaceAll(/\s+/g, '');
plan = plan.toLowerCase();
plan = plan.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase() + plan.substring(1);

for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++)
{
    if (select[i].text.includes(plan)) {
        select[i].selected = true;
    }
}

What I have tried:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    var select = document.getElementsByClassName("pp_pricing_options")[0];
    var plan = localStorage.getItem("Plan");
    plan = plan.replaceAll(/\s+/g, '');
    plan = plan.toLowerCase();
    plan = plan.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase() + plan.substring(1);

    for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++)
    {
      if (select[i].text.includes(plan)) {
          select[i].selected = true;
      }
    }
});

window.onload = function() {
     var select = document.getElementsByClassName("pp_pricing_options")[0];
     var plan = localStorage.getItem("Plan");
     plan = plan.replaceAll(/\s+/g, '');
     plan = plan.toLowerCase();
     plan = plan.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase() + plan.substring(1);

     for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++)
     {
         if (select[i].text.includes(plan)) {
             select[i].selected = true;
         }
     }
}

I have also tried the document ready function using jQuery.
I also tried the solutions in this link but my await keeps waiting with no response
How to wait until an element exists?
The code I typed:
$(document).ready(function () {
        async function waitForElm(selector) {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                    if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                    }

                    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
                            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                                    observer.disconnect();
                                    resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                            }
                    });

                    // If you get "parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'" error, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77855838/492336
                    observer.observe(document.body, {
                            childList: true,
                            subtree: true
                    });
            });
    }

    async function start(){
        var select = await waitForElm("pp_pricing_options");
        var plan = localStorage.getItem("Plan");
        plan = plan.replaceAll(/\s+/g, '');
        plan = plan.toLowerCase();
        plan = plan.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase() + plan.substring(1);

        for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++)
        {
            if (select[i].text.includes(plan)) {
                select[i].selected = true;
            }
        }
    } 
    start();
});

I believe the last one is the right solution but I can't get it to work for some reason. But please, if you have better/easier solution, tell me.

What's creating the element?

@evolutionxbox the plugin it self is the one creating the element

Does the plugin give you an event for when it's ready?

nope it does not

Which plugin is it? Maybe someone can take a look and see what we can advise?

@evolutionxbox this one. https://payment.page/

I recommend using a repeating setTimeout(). This way, you can check quickly and frequently only until the element loads:
{
 var check = () => {
  var select = document.getElementsByClassName("pp_pricing_options")[0];
  
  // Here you can check if any element was found.
  // If one wasn't found, call another setTimeout and cancel the rest of the code.
  if(!select) return setTimeout(check, 50);

  var plan = localStorage.getItem("Plan");
  plan = plan.replaceAll(/\s+/g, '');
  plan = plan.toLowerCase();
  plan = plan.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase() + plan.substring(1);
  for(var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
   if(select[i].text.includes(plan)) {
    select[i].selected = true;
   }
  }
 };

 // Start the first Timeout
 setTimeout(check, 50);
}


this solution is so flexible that i used it on 3 different pages until now thanks so much

You can use a timeout or perhaps just load the script at the end of <body>
//Timeout Method
setTimeout ( function() {
    var select = document.getElementsByClassName("pp_pricing_options")[0];
    var plan = localStorage.getItem("Plan");
    plan = plan.replaceAll(/\s+/g, '');
    plan = plan.toLowerCase();
    plan = plan.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase() + plan.substring(1);
    for(var i = 0; i < select.length; i++)
    {
        if(select[i].text.includes(plan)){
            select[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}, 1000); //change 1000 to the time delay you would like in milliseconds

