How to wait until an HTML Element doesn't exist?
I'm working in ReactJS. What is the best way to find out when an element has been removed, and does not exist? I prefer to use latest MutationObserverAPI  , unless ReactJs has library function to handle this.  I can select the Element by Id # attribute.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61511955/15435022
This is reference code to see when Element does not exist.
function waitForElm(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                observer.disconnect();
                resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
            }
        });

        // If you get "parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'" error, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77855838/492336
        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    });
}


On top of your function, just add this: if (!document.querySelector(selector) return;

ok @NVRM feel free to add in answer ,and I can send points, thanks

Is it solving your issue? No worries for points, but thank you.

Would using the useEffect's cleanup function work for you? The cleanup function only fires once the component is unmounted, but you can call functions and manage state within it. There's an example of this from their docs https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#connecting-to-an-external-system

hi @EricWebb feel free to write in code, and I can send points, thanks

So which elements are you trying to observe? Normally a mutation observer is good if you don't control the DOM in any way (eg: you're writing a browser extension). But if you have control over the DOM (which you often do in react) and you're rendering and are the one removing it, then perhaps a better way is for you to manage the removal as part of that?

Consider this parent/child component
Parent:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

interface Props { }

function Parent(props: Props) {
    const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false);

    function callback(id: number) {
        console.log(`Child ${id} removed from the dom`);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setShowChild(!showChild)}>Show/Hide Child</button>
            {showChild && <Child callback={callback} id={123456} />}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Parent;

Child:
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

interface Props {
    callback: (id: number) => void;
    id: number;
}

function Child(props: Props) {
    const { callback, id } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            callback(id);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {id}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Child;

With this setup, the function "callback" would only fire once the child component is unmounted and removed from the dom. Note that the useEffect cleanup function fires any time a dependency changes in the dependency array, as well as if the component unmounts. For your case, if you have a useEffect with no dependencies, it should serve your needs!
The MutationObserverApi works as well! My personal preference is to leverage useEffect, and if you have a specific component you're expecting to be removed from the dom, it's easier (at least in my mind) to have the code handling seeing if it unmounts/performing some action within the component itself!
Resources: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#connecting-to-an-external-system

You may use a ref Callback.
As you know, React will call this function with the DOM node when it's time to set the ref, and with null when it's time to clear it. For more about it, please see here How to manage a list of refs using a ref callback 
The following sample code demonstrates the same.
As you know, while toggling the state by the code, the element will be added and removed from DOM.
App.js
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [toggleLabel, setToggleLabel] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      {toggleLabel && (
        <label
          ref={(node) =>
            node ? console.log('Label1 creaded') : console.log('Label1 removed')
          }
        >
          Some Label
        </label>
      )}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setToggleLabel(!toggleLabel)}>
        Toggle Lable view, watch the logs
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

Test run - Console logs generated on loading and clicking the button
// Label1 creaded
// Label1 removed
// Label1 creaded
// Label1 removed
// Label1 creaded
// Label1 removed
// Label1 creaded

